# How to parse the ISO format datetime string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In pandas how can we make the datetime column from this data?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-02-04T22:03:44.846000+00:00']})
print(df)
                               date
0  2020-02-04T22:03:44.846000+00:00
```

I am not sure what is the letter "T" here.

## Attempts

```
pat = '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M%:%SZ'
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format=pat)

I am not sure what is the correct format here.
```

Comment: [`ISO 8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: @Felipe, thanks I got that, but now struggling the correct datetime format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse date time string format using this reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_columns = 10
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-02-04T22:03:44.846000+00:00']})

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df['hour'] = df['date1'].dt.hour

print(df)

0  2020-02-04T22:03:44.846000+00:00 2020-02-04 22:03:44.846000+00:00   

                             date2  hour  
0 2020-02-04 22:03:44.846000+00:00  22
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Felipe,

I got the answer.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-02-04T22:03:44.846000+00:00']})

df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
print(df)

                              date  year
0 2020-02-04 22:03:44.846000+00:00  2020
```